# Generic List<T> how to cast?

Tags: c#, xml, list, generics, casting

I have a Method which reads which kind of type an element is from a xml file. This process is happening in the "AnalyzeNodeLabel()" Method. Afterwards in this Method they get stored in Lists, either in one of classObjects or in one of interfaceObjects. By Type it should add it to a list.

My Code :

```
        List<T> getModel<T>(XmlReader reader, List<string> id) where T : BaseObject
        {

            List<ClassObject> classModels = new List<ClassObject>();
            List<InterfaceObject> interfaceModels = new List<InterfaceObject>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (id != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in id)
                    {
                        var baseModel = AnalyzeNodeLabel<BaseObject>(reader, item);
                        if (baseModel.GetType() == typeof(ClassObject))
                        {
                            classModels.Add((ClassObject)baseModel);
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(classModels,typeof(List<ClassObject>));
                        }
                        if (baseModel.GetType() == typeof(InterfaceObject))
                        {
                            interfaceModels.Add((InterfaceObject)baseModel);
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(interfaceModels,typeof(List<InterfaceObject>));
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But I'm getting converting problems. at the return(T)Convert... statements. A List is implicit not convertable to a List ...

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant, it doesn't support generic covariance

Comment: Just a helpful tip, you could just do `List<T> models = new List<T>();` and work around the problem entirely

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Is there a way where I can add the object elements of models to a list which is not generic and has instead the right object type?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly cast `List<A>` to `List<a>` where `a:A` due to covariance (because `typeof(List<A>)` doesn't inherit from `typeof(List<a>)`.

However, there's a linq [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `List<Child> children` to `List<Base> bases`

The reason is that if the compiler let you safely do that. Here is why

```csharp
class Base {}
class Child1 : Base {}
class Child2 : Base {}

var children = new List<Child1>();
var bases = (List<Base>)children; // Let's assume this is acceptable

bases.Add(new Child2());          // Now this will add an instance of Child2
                                  // to a List<Child1> which should not be possible
```

If you are only planning to read from `children`, you can safely convert it to `IReadOnlyList<Base>`. That is safe as `IReadOnlyList<>` interface does not allow modification. [See this for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

Alternatively, if you **need a list of the base class**, you can create a new `List<Base>` from `List<Child1>` using [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast) and [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) extension methods:

```csharp
using System.Linq;
...

Base[] bases = children.Cast<Base>().ToList();
```